# Hartree-Fock exchange energy: can $i = j$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, many-body, density-functional-theory

I am trying to understand the Hartree-Fock exchange energy used in a paper by Becke and Roussel [1], where it's defined as:

$$\begin{align}
E_X &= \sum\limits_{\sigma} E_{X\sigma} \tag{1}\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{\sigma} \int\text{d}^3\textbf r_1 \text{d}^3\textbf r_2 \frac{|\rho_{{\textbf r_1}\sigma}(\textbf r_1, \textbf r_2)|^2}{|\textbf r_1-\textbf r_2|}\tag{2}
\end{align}$$
where the one-body spin-density matrix $\rho_{{\textbf r_1}\sigma}(\textbf r_1, \textbf r_2)$ of the Hartree-Fock determinant is given by:
$$
\begin{align}
\rho_{{\textbf r_1}\sigma}(\textbf r_1, \textbf r_2) = \sum\limits_i^\sigma \psi_i^*(\textbf r_1)\psi_i^*(\textbf r_2) \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
This implies that there can be a term with four wave functions $\psi$, each having the same index $i$.

In contrast, the Hartree-Fock exchange energy as I have seen it in my lectures usually involves a sum $\sum_{i\neq j}$, i.e. where there cannot be a term with four $\psi$'s each having the same index $i$.

Am I confusing something here? Should there be a $\sum_{i\neq j}$, or are the sums over $i$ and $j$ really independent?

---

[1] [Becke, Roussel, Phys. Rev. A 39, 3761 (1989)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.39.3761)